# Retrieve articles with multiple specified tags(m2m to article)

Tags: django

I have an article model which share ManyToMany relationships with  model Tag,

I'd like to retrieve articles which have multiple tags

for one tag:

```
In [162]: articles = Article.objects.filter(tags__name="python")
Out[162]: <QuerySet [<Tag: python>, <Tag: django>
```

As for multiple tags I tried

```
In [168]: articles = Article.objects.filter(tags__name="python", tags__name="django", tags__name="queryset")
```

It reported error:

```
SyntaxError: keyword argument repeated
```

How could I get the articles which have the specified tags.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`__in`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#in) lookup:

```
articles = Article.objects.filter(tags__name__in=["python", "django", "queryset"])
```

Comment: impressive, but __in is `or` logic, could it be logic `and`?

Comment: @Humbler I am afraid no. If you need and use Q objects.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Q` objects:

```
from django.db.models import Q

Article.objects.filter(Q(tags='python') | Q(tags='django') | Q(tags='queryset'))
```

This roughly translates to:

```
"SELECT * FROM Article WHERE tags='python' OR tags='django' OR tags='queryset'"
```